# Python 3.5 Asyncio and Multiple websocket servers

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio

I am using Python websockets 4.0.1 on Ubuntu. I want to have 2 websocket servers running. I was able to get this to "kind of work" by creating 2 threads and independent event loops for each one. By "kind of work", I mean both websockets work and are responsive for about 30 seconds and then one of them stops. I have to restart the process to get them both to work again. If I only run one or the other of these 2 threads, the single websocket works forever.

What am I doing wrong and how can I have 2 websockets work forever with asyncio?

```
# Start VL WebSocket Task
class vlWebSocketTask (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        # Main while loops
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        while True:
            try:
                print("Starting VL WebSocket Server...")
                startVLServer = websockets.serve(vlWebsocketServer, '192.168.1.3', 8777)
                asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(startVLServer)  
                asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
            except Exception as ex:
                print(ex)
            time.sleep(5)

# Start IR WebSocket Task
class irWebSocketTask (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        while True:
            try:
                print("Starting IR WebSocket Server...")
                startIRServer = websockets.serve(irWebsocketServer, '192.168.1.3', 8555)
                asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(startIRServer)  
                asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
            except Exception as ex:
                print(ex)
            time.sleep(5)
        
# Initialize VL WebSocket Task
#VLWebSocketTask = vlWebSocketTask()
#VLWebSocketTask.start()
        
# Initialize IR WebSocket Task
IRWebSocketTask = irWebSocketTask()
IRWebSocketTask.start()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need threads to run multiple asyncio tasks - allowing multiple agents to share the same event loop is the strong suit of asyncio. You should be able to replace both thread-based classes with code like this:

```
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(websockets.serve(vlWebsocketServer, '192.168.1.3', 8777))
loop.run_until_complete(websockets.serve(irWebsocketServer, '192.168.1.3', 8555))
loop.run_forever()
```

While it is not exactly *wrong* to mix threads and asyncio, doing so correctly requires care not to mix up the separate asyncio instances. The safe way to use threads for asyncio is with `loop.run_in_executor()`, which runs synchronous code in a separate thread without blocking the event loop, while returning an object `await`able from the loop.

Note: the above code was written prior to the advent of `asyncio.run()` and manually spins the event loop. In Python 3.7 and later one would probably write something like:

```
async def main():
    server1 = await websockets.serve(vlWebsocketServer, '192.168.1.3', 8777)
    server2 = await websockets.serve(irWebsocketServer, '192.168.1.3', 8555)
    await asyncio.gather(server1.wait_closed(), server2.wait_closed())

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Have you tried running your own code? This would yield something like `TypeError: a coroutine was expected, got <websockets.server.Serve object at 0x7baca53e3a90>`.

Comment: @AndyPan I don't remember if I tried this, but it's entirely possible that I didn't. It's also possible that `serve` was defined as an `async def` two years ago when this answer was written. Either way, `loop.create_task` can trivially be changed to `asyncio.ensure_future` with the desired effect. If you can confirm that that works, I'll change the answer accordingly.

Comment: First, apparently you should await on the returned object. This will give you the server object. Then use something like `asyncio.create_task(server.wait_closed())`.

Comment: @AndyPan Thanks, I've now amended the answer. Note that `wait_closed()` is a convenient await target when you run inside `asyncio.run()`, but passing `wait_closed()` to `create_task()` is unnecessary because once `server()` completes, the server runs regardless of whether you call `wait_closed()`. The pre-`asyncio.run` code in this answer uses `run_forever()` to keep the loop running and therefore doesn't need `wait_closed()`. In the edit I've included the modern way of accomplishing the same goal which does use `wait_closed()` as you'd expect.

Comment: Apologize for my arrogance. The return object of `websockets.serve` has not changed, but my understanding of how it works is inaccurate as well. As I cannot find a solution throughout the official docs, thanks for improving the answer.

Comment: @AndyPan No worries, I'm no fan of untested code myself, and your comments did result in improvements to the answer. I'm not sure what kind of official solution you're looking for, but the (second) code in the answer seems pretty clear and idiomatic.