# running multiple websocket connections

Tags: python, websocket

Here's the snippet of code that I have

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def get_cells(websocket, path):
    async for message in websocket:
        ... some code

async def get_shaded_area(websocket, path):
    async for message in websocket:
        ... #some code


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
    websockets.serve(get_cells, 'localhost', 8765))

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
    websockets.serve(get_shaded_area, 'localhost/shade-area', 8765))

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

it started with only `get_cells` so it only had one `get_event_loop` for `get_cells` at that point it was working ok.

Since I want to make more that one ws connection since each handles different data and returns different results the second `get_shaded_area` after adding it throws this error:

```
(pixelart) sam@sam-Lenovo-G51-35:~/code/pixelart$ python path.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "path.py", line 144, in <module>
    websockets.serve(get_shaded_area, 'localhost/shade-area', 8765))
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 473, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py", line 537, in _wrap_awaitable
    return (yield from awaitable.__await__())
File "/home/sam/code/envs/pixelart/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/py35/server.py", line 13, in __await_impl__
    server = await self._creating_server
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1019, in create_server
    infos = yield from tasks.gather(*fs, loop=self)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 968, in _create_server_getaddrinfo
    flags=flags, loop=self)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 56, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Comment: Should the websockets be on different ports - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48818716/python-3-5-asyncio-and-multiple-websocket-servers and both on ‘localhost’?

Answer (score 2):

I posted a question to the github repo for this package and got back a simple solution.

```
async def get_cells(websocket):
    async for message in websocket:
        ...

async def get_shaded_area(websocket):
    async for message in websocket:
        ...

async def router(websocket, path):
    if path == "/":
        await get_cells(websocket, path)
    elif path == "/shade-area":
        await get_shaded_area(websocket, path)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
    websockets.serve(router, 'localhost', 8765))

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't run several servers on same `host:port` pair, instead you should handle the path passed - the path is an endpoint, client r requesting during WS connection.

The proper pattern would be to create a "router" which would do the job for you. [Example](https://repl.it/repls/LatestCommonVoxels) code (simple code to show what i mean):

```
import asyncio
import websockets


async def get_shaded_area(message):
  print('shade-area:' + message)


async def get_cells(messzage):
  print('Cells area:' + messzage)


async def router(websocket, path):
  async for message in websocket:
    if path == "/shade-area":
      await get_shaded_area(message)
    else:
      await get_cells(message)


def main():
  asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(websockets.serve(router, '127.0.0.1', 8765))
  asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```